# css float issue in ie6&ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I have a float issue in IE6&ie7:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>lily</title>
    <style>
        div{width: 100px; height: 100px;}
        .div1{background: red; float: left;}
        .div2{background: yellow;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">div1</div>
        <div class="div2">div2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

why it displays different in IE6&&IE7 and Chrome? And how to solve it in ie6&ie7?

:[image]

Comment: What do you want to have happen?

Comment: I want to know why it displays different in IE6&&IE7 and Chrome?

Comment: But what do you want it do display like? Side by side? On top of one another? Between your code and your screen shots, I couldn't really tell what you *want* it to look like.

Comment: Why would you only float the left one? If they are both block level elements, and you float just one... it's a mess in any browser. In the most up to date chrome, it looks like the image on the right.

Comment: When you float something, it changes the natural flow. See my Fiddle below in your browser(s) - Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `div` is clearing your first, but only the text. If you set a left margin you can tell it to sit next to the floated div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pjvtb/

```
.div2 {
    margin-left: 100px; /* new line */
    background: yellow;
}
```

**Note:** IE 6 and 7 incorrectly move the second `div` past the first one, due to `hasLayout`. You can search online for more information about the problems associated with it. There is also a `3px` "text jog" present in IE 6 (possibly 7 too, I can't remember) which usually meant, to display the same in all browsers, one would actually make the `margin-left: 103px` to accommodate IE's weirdness.

Comment: actually I want to know how to make ie6 and ie7 display it like chrome, because it's a ie bug?

Comment: The bug is that the item clears the float without meaning to; if the point is to have two `div`s side-by-side with different colours, then achieving it involves making Chrome look like IE. If you want IEs to look like how Chrome currently looks, then you don't need a `background-color` on the div at all, simply add `clear: left;` to the `.div2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>lily</title>
<style>
    div{width: 100px; height: 100px;}
    .div1{background: red; float: left;}
    .div2{background: yellow; clear:both;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First things first, try it with both of the divs floating and see what happens.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/883y6/) is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/883y6/) with each scenario for you to test.

```
 /* yours */
.yours div {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
}

.yours .div1 {
    background: red; 
    float: left;
}

.yours .div2 {
    background: yellow;
}


/* mine */
.mine div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.mine .div1 {
    background: red;
}

.mine .div2 {
    background: yellow;
}


/* mine with a cleared float */
.mine-too div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.mine-too .div1 {
    background: red;
}

.mine-too .div2 {
    background: yellow;
    clear: left;
    /* not BOTH - you only need left - there is no right... */
}
```